# Imagecreatefromstring and resize

Tags: php, stream

i m trying to get an image from db and resize it earlier that the client recive it.
This work correctly but naturally the image is fully sized:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
```

So i have tryed this:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        if ($im !== false) {
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

            $percent = 0.5;
            $width = imagesx($im);
            $height = imagesy($im);
            $newwidth = $width * $percent;
            $newheight = $height * $percent;

            $img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h);
            imagecopyresized($img,$im,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,$width,$height);

            imagejpeg($im);
            imagedestroy($im);
        }
```

but the browser return an error saying "the image can't be displayed beacause contains errors".

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Download the faulty image, open it with a text editor and look for error messages.

Comment: i think you changes the $new_w,$new_h values

Comment: Have you tried echoing the new width and height, seeing if this is correct?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few errors in your code:
1) you should return $img, not $im...

```
        imagejpeg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
```

2) you defined $newwidth and $newheight, but in the following code you used $new_w, $new_h.

Correct code:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        $percent = 0.5;
        $width = imagesx($im);
        $height = imagesy($im);
        $newwidth = $width * $percent;
        $newheight = $height * $percent;

        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
        imagecopyresized($img,$im,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

        imagejpeg($img);
        imagedestroy($img);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w,$new_h);
            imagecopyresized($img,$im,0,0,0,0,$new_w,$new_h,$width,$height);
```

Into this:

```
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
            imagecopyresized($img,$im,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
```